# Selecting line between 2 points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

I have a point layer representing intersections and a line layer representing roads. The point layer has XY coordinates for each intersection and the line layer has START_XY and END_XY coordinates for each line segment.

I couldn't seem to find a way to select segments between specific intersections. So if I had something like the following:

[image]

How could I select the segment between (50,90) and (32,64)?

Comment: It's not clear how you intend to use nodes as a way of selecting the road segment. Can't you just select the line with the select tool? Add more information to your question.

Comment: Selects work on table records. Is each segment a different record?